# Executing invoke-item remotely in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to execute this code willing to execute the program server.exe in the remote machine NODO-R01.Command completes, but nothing happens:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName NODO-R01 {Invoke-item C:\server.exe}
```

If I use any other *-Item cmdlet it works; like deleting, renaming, etc.

Comment: Nothing happens.....sorry to hear that, are you looking for our condolences? A little more detail might be in order. Maybe something along the lines of "if I run server.exe locally, it gives me this output; therefore I expected something similar running it remotely" Help us help you!

Comment: try adding `;write-host "Hello World"` after the Invoke-Item to check that the command is actually running something.